# How to log db queries in Lumen5.7?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, lumen

I upgrade Lumen from 5.4 to 5.7, and I want to be able to log DB queries for debugging.

Here's the conf/source code. I have to use '**LumenDB**' alias because of naming conflict of a third-party library.

I expect the query could be logged, but I can not see them in lumen.log.

## MyApplication.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;
use Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter;
use Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler;
use Monolog\Logger;

class MyApplication extends \Laravel\Lumen\Application {
    public function withFacades($aliases = true, $userAliases = [])
    {
        Facade::setFacadeApplication($this);

        if (! static::$aliasesRegistered) {
            static::$aliasesRegistered = true;

            class_alias('Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth', 'Auth');
            class_alias('Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache', 'Cache');
            class_alias('Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB', 'LumenDB');
            class_alias('Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event', 'Event');
            class_alias('Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate', 'Gate');
            class_alias('Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log', 'Log');
            class_alias('Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue', 'Queue');
            class_alias('Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema', 'Schema');
            class_alias('Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator', 'Validator');
        }
    }

    protected function registerLogBindings()
    {
        $this->singleton('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface', function () {
            return new Logger('lumen', $this->getMonologHandler());
        });
    }

    protected function getMonologHandler()
    {
        $maxFiles = 7;
        $rotatingLogHandler = new RotatingFileHandler(storage_path('logs/lumen.log'), $maxFiles);
        $rotatingLogHandler->setFormatter(new LineFormatter(null, null, true, true));
        $handlers = [];
        $handlers[] = $rotatingLogHandler;
        return $handlers;
    }
}
```

## bootstrap/app.php

```
$app->register(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class);
$app->register(App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class);



\LumenDB::connection()->enableQueryLog();
```

## app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        DB::listen(function ($query) {
            // $query->sql
            // $query->bindings
            // $query->time
            Log::info("-------");
            Log::info($query->sql);
        });
    }
```

The query is executed inside a Service method which is called by a Command scheduled by cron.

```
public function getAllStatsToday()
{
    $today = new \DateTime();
    $today->setTime(0, 0, 0);
    $productUsageStats = ProductUsageStat::make()
        ->where('updated_at', '>', $today)
        ->get();
    return $productUsageStats;
}
```

Comment: Could you also provide your config/logging.php? And have you restarted the application?

Comment: @SvenHakvoort I don't have config/logging.php, the logging is configured in MyApplication (I just edited the post), I can see the other logs except db log. What does 'restart application' mean? I only updated the source files onto the server.

Comment: Seems that the 'function ($query)' never get called for some reason.

Comment: I copy logging.cpp from vendor/laravel to config, it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You have not registered the `AppServiceProvider` in your `bootstrap/app.php`. Because of this the `boot` method in your `AppServiceProvider` is never registered and thus the logging is never executed.

You should change `app.php` to the following:

```
$app->register(App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class);

$app->register(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class);

\LumenDB::connection()->enableQueryLog();
```

Comment: AppServiceProvider is registered. I missed the line in my post.